# Which pattern use in MEANJS project?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I recently move in NodeJs from PHP and developing a project in MEANJS. But i unable to use a controller method in other controller. I think that i have followed wrong pattern.

```
student.model.js
-----------------
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var studentSchema = new Schema({
     ....
     ....
}) 

student.controller.js
---------------------
var Student = require('../models/student.model');
module.exports.get = function(req, res, next) {
   var where={};
   if(req.body.hasOwnproperty('id')){
      where._id=req.body.id;
    }
    ....
    ....
    Student.find(where)
        .populate({ path: 'createdBy', select: '_id name' })
        .exec(function(err, studentData) {
            if (err)
               return res.status(500).end(err.message);
               res.status(200).json(studentData);
           })
}

report.controller.js
---------------------
var StudentCtrl = require('../controller/student.controller');
module.exports.getStudentGrade = function(req, res, next) {
  //HERE I WANT get StudentCtrl.get data then response to client

  //somethings like----------------
  StudentCtrl.get(req,res,next){
     //get studentData here
     //manipulation on studentData
     res.status(200).json(myReportData);
  }
 //-------------------

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 versions on `student.controller.get`, for example `student.controller.getCallback` which receives a callback which you can then use in `report.controller.js`

```
student.controller.js
---------------------
var Student = require('../models/student.model');
module.exports.get = function(req, res, next) {
   var where={};
   if(req.body.hasOwnproperty('id')){
      where._id=req.body.id;
    }
    ....
    ....
    Student.find(where)
        .populate({ path: 'createdBy', select: '_id name' })
        .exec(function(err, studentData) {
            if (err)
               return res.status(500).end(err.message);
               res.status(200).json(studentData);
        })
}

module.exports.getCallback = function(req, callback) {
   var where={};
   if(req.body.hasOwnproperty('id')){
      where._id=req.body.id;
    }
    ....
    ....
    Student.find(where)
        .populate({ path: 'createdBy', select: '_id name' })
        .exec(callback);
}

report.controller.js
---------------------
var StudentCtrl = require('../controller/student.controller');
module.exports.getStudentGrade = function(req, res, next) {
  //HERE I WANT get StudentCtrl.get data then response to client

  //somethings like----------------
  StudentCtrl.getCallback(req, function(err, myReportData) {
     //get studentData here
     //manipulation on studentData
     if (err)
         return res.status(500).end(err.message);
     res.status(200).json(myReportData);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

MEAN Stack is a complete JavaScript framework, it is a mixed of Mango dB, Express JS, Angular JS and Node JS. here Node JS play the role of server-side programming and npm server, so if you are re-forming the framework it makes into you have to independently connect MangodB, Express JS, Angular JS to PHP. please refer the link http://meanjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:
mongo

- index.js

  - models

    1. user.js
    2. client.js
  - controllers

    1. user.js
    2. client.js

Now 
in models put all the schemas

and in controller call relevant schemas and function like save() update etc

and in the last all the controller method access it in the index hs